# SP-initiated SAML Logout Request - is this supported?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have Salesforce set up as an IdP, with a custom app acting as the SP. I have SP-initiated login via SAML implemented, following [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-Custom-.Net-Application).

I'd like to enable SP-initiated logout as well, but I cannot find any resources on this, except for [this discussion](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjseAAC) which seems to indicate it is not supported - but this seems to be geared toward the scenario where Salesforce is the SP.

Can anyone clarify whether Salesforce as a IdP supports SP-initiated SAML logout requests?

Comment: I've never been able to configure Salesforce to do SLO, either where they are the SP or the IdP.

Answer (score 1):

It appears true SLO is not available, but we were able to implement a "poor man's" version of it:

SP-initiated logout: On the log out page of our custom app, we included a hidden IFrame to `our-salesforce-community-url/secur/logout.jsp`. A request to this will log the user out of Salesforce.

IdP-initiated logout: Per configuration, after logout the user is redirected to a logout page in our custom app, which causes them to be logged out.